# Issue with unicode superscript - (minus) to name each facet panel through named character string in a plot in r

Tags: r, unicode

I am attempting to create a character string to title my facet panels by pasting the Unicode symbols where I need them like this.

```
labs <- c("one", "two", "three⁻¹") 

names(labs) <- c("1", "2", "3")
```

However, when plotted, it shows up as a small box and not superscript `-`, while superscript `1` works just fine.

Comment: Unicode is just a mapping from numbers to glyph in a fontbase. I don't think you know what font you are working with or at least what that mapping might be in the numeric range you were hoping had meaning. See the help page for `?points` It will allow you to see at least some of hte glyphs for numbers in the range up to 255.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way to do superscript for the labels, where we can define in `factor`, then use `labeller` in `facet_wrap` of `ggplot2`. Idea taken from [here](https://www.datanovia.com/en/blog/how-to-change-ggplot-facet-labels/) in the comments.

```
library(tidyverse)

data("ToothGrowth")
df <- ToothGrowth

df$dose <- factor(
  df$dose,
  levels = c("0.5", "1", "2"),
  labels = c("one",
             "two",
             "three^{-1}")
)

# Plot
ggplot(df, aes(x = supp, y = len)) +
  geom_boxplot() +
  facet_wrap( ~ dose, labeller = label_parsed)
```

**Output**

[image]